# How To Prevent Nav Icon from Being Pushed Upward

Tags: jquery, html, css

Beginner here. I'm trying to make a responsive Navbar with a nav icon that transforms to an x-button. I can't figure out why my nav icon is being pushed upward by the drop-down menu when clicked. Please see my HTML, CSS and Jquery codes below. Hope someone could help. Thanks.

HTML:

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <div class="nav-icon">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropbtn">Continents
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="north-america.html">North America</a>
        <a href="south-america.html">South America</a>
        <a href="africa.html">Africa</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-icon {
  margin-left: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.navbar {
  display: none;
  /*for mobile*/
}
.nav-expanded {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Jquery:

```
var $navicon = $(".nav-icon");
var $window = $(window);
var $navbar = $(".navbar");

/*transform nav icon to xbutton*/
function changeIcon() {
    $navicon.children().addClass("change");
}

function hasChangeClass() {
    if ($navicon.children().hasClass("change")) {
        return true;
    }
}

$navicon.click("slow", function() {
    if (!hasChangeClass()) {
        changeIcon();
      $navbar.slideToggle(600, function() {
                $navbar.toggleClass("nav-expanded").css("display", ""); 
            }); 
     } else {
        $navicon.children().removeClass("change");
        $navbar.hide();
     }
});

$window.resize(function resize(){
    if ($window.width() < 768) {
        $navbar.removeClass("nav-expanded");
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question does not have all the related css classes, please first make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for your code and then edit your post, add all the needed css classes and also the link to the fiddle.